# Entity Framework Linq to SQL creating duplicate entries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, ef-code-first

I have some code in an asynchronous task that checks to see if a record exists using SingleOrDefaultAsync and if it does not, then it creates it.

Intermittently I've been noticing duplicate entries appearing.  Further investigation shows that the records are being created milliseconds apart which makes me think if there are multiple threads attempting to check and write the same value.  So at the point where the check occurs, the value does not exist, so "Thread 1" writes the value to the database, but "Thread 2" has already done the same check and also writes the value to the database.

I'm a bit wary about putting a semaphoreslim around this code and unfortunately I cannot replicate it locally either but I can 100% see its happening in production.  Any advice?

Comment: Why not introduce a unique constraint on this? Then the DB itself would at least throw an exception.

Comment: Hi Alex, yes you're right and that is what should have been done to begin with which is something we will be doing but right now we're on the proverbial back foot so if we try putting a unique constraint on the field, it'll fail to apply when the software is deployed due to the duplicated values. I have created a script that is periodically run to consolidate the values (delete the duplicates) so the symptoms are being addressed but its just so frustrating why this occurs to begin with...

Comment: If you write with multiple threads and can't use a constraint yes, it's getting quite hard. You might increase the lock-level of the database but this will limit throughput dramatically. The best approach for this would be, to prevent WRITING for a given time, clean up the database from duplicate values, introduce the unique constrain, and release the write lock. I don't see any better solution to this now.

Comment: Maybe your data generation is wrong to start with. Why are multiple threads writing the same data to DB? On what type of source do they work?

Comment: It doesn't happen all the time but I have identified the potential scenario in which it does.  So, I'm putting in steps that will allow the unique index to go onto the table where the data is tidied up shortly before the unique index is done.  This will minimise the chance of it occuring before the index is in place.  But thanks for your help @Alex